# safe 301 redirection using htaccess for two domains

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, seo, rewritecond, 301-redirect

I have two domains, a new domain (newdomain.com) and and old legacy domain (olddomain.com). I want to safely redirect the old domain to the new domain. Easy enough.

At the moment I am doing this using htaccess ModReWrite like so

```
# Redirect WWW's
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which basically says rewrite any domain that isn't the new one, to the new one. I'm not 100% sure if this is safe for search engines? Should I redirect the old domain separately?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct for SEO. Search engines will update their database that the old URL has changed to the new URL. You should leave it active like that for at least several months to they all get a chance to update, and visitors can still use the old URL.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this blog post helpful

http://www.realestatewebmasters.com/blogs/morgan-carey/9408/show/